# Pointers and char[] in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I don't understand how these codes work:

1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char x[] = "gate2011";
char *ptr = x;
printf ("%s", ptr+ptr[3]-ptr[1]);
return 0;
}
```

*// 2011*

2) This one gives me a blank output although the app says that it should result *ineapp*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char x[] = "sanguineapp";
char *ptr = x;
printf ("%s", ptr+ptr[5]-ptr[2]);
return 0;
}
```

3) And also this one and the output should be *nguineapp*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char x[] = "sanguineapp";
char *ptr = x;
printf ("%s", ptr+ptr[9]-ptr[4]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this out? just by looking at the code I would expect the following output: 1) "te2011", 2) "guineapp" 3) "ineapp"

Comment: I've already put the outputs in my question and you got them all wrong, comparing with the answers from the app's quiz. Can you please explain how you solved them?

Comment: @user287107 2011 in the first riddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know how all these three code blocks works, you got to start reading good `C` book specially array and pointers concept.

**Case 1 :-** In the below code block

```
int main(void) {
    char x[] = "gate2011";
    char *ptr = x;
    printf ("%s", ptr+ptr[3]-ptr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like

```
 x[0]   x[1]   x[2]     x[3]   x[4]    x[5]     x[6]   x[7]    x[8]
 0x100  0x101  0x102   0x103   ..                                   -->(assume 0x100 is base address of x )
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
| g   |   a   |   t   |   e   |   2   |   0   |  1   |   1   |   \0   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
x
ptr (ptr = x, i.e ptr points to base address of x)
```

This

```
ptr+ptr[3]-ptr[1]) == 0x100 + ( 'e' - 'a' )
                   == 0x100 +  4
                   == 0x104
```

So when `printf()` executes it will start printing from `0x104` until `\0`, hence it prints `2011`.

**Case 2 :-**  In the below code block

```
int main(void){
        char x[] = "sanguineapp";
        char *ptr = x;
        printf ("%s", ptr+ptr[5]-ptr[2]);
        return 0;
}
```

It looks like

```
x[0]   x[1]   x[2]     x[3]   x[4]    x[5]     x[6]   x[7]    x[8] ..
 0x100  0x101  0x102   0x103   ..                                   --> (assume 0x100 is base address of x )
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s   |   a   |   n   |   g   |   u   |   i   |  n   |   e   |   a   |  p  | \0  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x
ptr (ptr = x, i.e ptr points to base address of x)
```

This

```
ptr+ptr[5]-ptr[2] == 0x100 + ( 'i' - 'n' )
                  == 0x100 + ( -5) /* so it will try to access invalid memory i.e base address 5 */
```

So when `printf()` executes, since you are providing wrong address to `printf()`, o/p of this statement causes **undefined behavior**, you are lucky that it didn't crashes.

Same happens in third case also.

Answer (score 0):

its a quite unsafe code :)

if you replace the two array accesses, you will get

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char x[] = "gate2011";
char *ptr = x;
printf ("%s", ptr+'e'-'a');
return 0;
}
```

if you look at the ascii table, you find that 'e'-'a' is  4. this results to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char x[] = "gate2011";
char *ptr = x;
printf ("%s", ptr+4);
return 0;
}
```

which tells printf to start printing the string while skipping the first 4 items

the second does not work,
it gives prints ptr - 5, so it actually accesses the memory at a random undefined location

the others are similar

Comment: But on the next one, in the ascii table n is '.'

Comment: the next one gives a negative result, thats why this code is quite unsafe

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: When writing here, please use the usual English conventions for case and punctuation - broadly all sentences should start with a capital letter, and end with some sort of punctuation mark.